# How to identify change to the "Modified By", "Created By" , "CheckOutTo" column title through REST API

Tags: web-services, document, soap, rest

I am an iOS developer. In one of my application, I need to make modified by, created by and checkoutto user's information along with the document/list item information from SharePoint server through REST API call. But if I change the column name "Modified By"(default) by some other value "WHO MODIFIED", my API call fails.

Example : `<site_address>/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/?$expand=CreatedBy,ModifiedBy,CheckedOutTo`

Is there a way to know what is the new title for those column values through a small REST or SOAP API call?

Answer (score 1):

CreatedBy  is actual Author
ModifiedBy is actually Editor
CheckOut To is actually the CheckoutUser

The best way to see these names (unless you use tools like Visual Studio 2010, SharePoint Manager 2010, etc.) is directly in the browser by looking at field(column) properties and in the URL you shall get the actual name of the field and not the Display Name.

These are automatically populated by SharePoint during operations.

Answer (score 0):

FOR CREATED BY:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Pages')/items(1)?$select=Author/Name,Author/Title&$expand=Author/Id
```

FOR MODIFIED BY:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Pages')/items(1)?$select=Editor/Name,Editor/Title&$expand=Editor/Id
```

I TRIED THIS QUERY. IT WILL GIVE YOU THE CREATED BY OR MODIFIED BY USER'S DISPLAY NAME